# Disable BDPROCHOT (thermal throttling) in Linux?

Tags: power-management, battery

My laptop throttles to 400 Mhz whenever I connect it to charger. Without charger it works perfectly. For workaround I was using ThrottleStop on Windows and disabling BDPROCHOT there worked for me. My laptop never overheated even after disabling BDPROCHOT.

Recently I switched to Ubuntu 16 and I'm experiencing the same 400Mhz cap on my CPU speed. I tried switching to and from Powersave mode to Performance mode, it didnt work. I also tried to disable OnDemand CPU Scaling but that didnt work as well.

So, is there any way that I can disable the BDPROCHOT the same way I disabled it on Windows?

Please explain clearly. I'm not more of a tech guy.

Any help will be highly appreciated.